# ngx-formly ng-select formcontrol change emitted value

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect, ngx-formly

I have a formly form with a custom typeahead field using ng-select multi select. It currently emits an array of key value pairs. I need it to emit an array of just values. Seems like this should be a roughly straight forward task but I'm struggling to figure out out to do it. Will post updates as I try different things. I can build a helper to intercept the model and reformat it but there must be  clean way to do that within the formcontrol.

typeahead.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-kup-typeahead',
  template: `
    <ng-select
      [items]="options$ | async"
      [ngClass]="{'ng-select-required': to.required}"
      [placeholder]="to.label"
      [typeahead]="search$"
      [formControl]="formControl"
      [multiple]="to.multiple"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
    >
    </ng-select>
  `,
})
export class KupTypeaheadComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();
  search$ = new EventEmitter();
  options$;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options$ = this.search$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      startWith(''),
      filter(v => v !== null),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(this.to.search$),
    );

    this.options$.subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy$.complete();
  }

  onChange(item: any) {
    console.warn('onChange ', item);
  }
}
```

form-config.ts

```
   {
      key: 'genotype.ploidy',
      id: 'filter_ploidy',
      type: 'kup-typehead',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Filter by Ploidy',
        multiple: true,
        options: of(res['creation_method']),
        search$: (term: string) => {
          return this.dropdownService.getDropdown('genotypes/ploidies', '', '', term);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that should be done by `ng-select` somehow, try passing `bindValue` input (check their doc).
From Formly side, we rely on `formControl` to control the emitted value, the solution is to remove  `[formControl]="formControl"` input and rely on `onChange` event but not recommended:

```
  onChange(item: any) {
    this.formControl.setValue(item);
  }
```

another way is to use `parsers`:

```
export class KupTypeaheadComponent {
  defaultOptions: {
    parsers: [(value) => ...],
  }
}
```